# Java ASM help need

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I write a simple program using Java ASM to generate the byte code which is generated by compiling the following class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

The code I wrote to generate the bytecode for this class is given below.

```
public class CodeGenerator {

    public void generateClass()
    {
        ClassWriter cw=new ClassWriter(Opcodes.NULL);
        FieldVisitor fv;
        MethodVisitor mv;
        cw.visit(Opcodes.V1_1, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "Main", null, "java/lang/Object", null);
        mv=cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
        mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.AALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
        mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
        mv.visitEnd();
        mv=cw.visitMethod(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC+ Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, "Main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V", null, null);
        mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream");
        mv.visitLdcInsn("Test");
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
        mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
        mv.visitEnd();
        cw.visitEnd();
        this.WriteClass(cw);
    }
    public void WriteClass(ClassWriter cw){
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try{
            fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Acadamic\\Final year project\\ASM\\Main.class");
            fos.write(cw.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(CodeGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles successfully and when I try to run it, it gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: main.class.  Program will exit.
```

can any one please help me for avoid this error. If anyone can explain the cause to the error and how to avoid it, please be kind enough to help me.

Thank You.

***Follow-up:***

When I run it like java Main it gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "out" in class Main
 has illegal signature "Ljava/io/PrintStream"
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Main.  Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think your error is being caused by ASM. It looks like you simply called `java` incorrectly. You should call it like this:

```
java Main
```

My guess is that you called it like this:

```
java Main.class
```

### Update

There are three problems with your code.

#### Problem #1

The `ClassWriter` constructor accepts a bit mask of options. You passed it `Opcodes.NULL`. Although this may *seem* correct, you actually want to pass it `0` (`Opcodes.NULL` means something different).

```
ClassWriter cw=new ClassWriter(0);
```

#### Problem #2

You are calling `AALOAD` in the constructor instead of `ALOAD`. The `AALOAD` instruction loads an *array element*, whereas `ALOAD` loads a *local variable*.

```
mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
```

#### Problem #3

In your `Main` method, you forgot the semicolon after `Ljava/io/PrintStream`:

```
mv.visitFieldInsn(
    Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
    "java/lang/System",
    "out",
    "Ljava/io/PrintStream;" // Notice the semicolon
  );
```

You can save yourself some pain by taking advantage of ASM's `Type` class:

```
mv.visitFieldInsn(
    Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
    "java/lang/System",
    "out",
    Type.getObjectType("java/io/PrintStream").getDescriptor()
  );
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. When I run it like java Main it gives another error. I have mentioned it here

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, By experience I have found that illegal signature error generally comes due to missing semicolon at end of method description.